# SQL Query to find duplicate data across columns

Tags: sql, find, db2, duplicates, row

I am trying to query a DB2 table to find duplicates across columns.  To be more specific, I am looking for rows where there are duplicate columns but not necessarily across the same column name.

Example.

**Graph_Table** has four columns of coordinates

**Row1**

```
Column1 = -1
Column2 = -4
column3 = 6
column4 = 3
```

**Row7**

```
Column1 = 3
Column2 = -1
Column3 = 6
Column4 = -4
```

The query would count this as a duplicate or return the result set as duplicates because the coordinates are the same but not from the same column.  I have researched several queries but they all operate using the ordinal rows/values for the comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2 supports `lateral` and `listagg()`.  Hence, I think you can do:

```
select gt.*
from (select gt.*, count(*) over (partition by v.cols) as cnt
      from graph_table gt, lateral
           (select listagg(col, ',') within group (order by col) as cols
            from (values (gt.column1), (gt.column2), (gt.column3), (gt.column4)
                 ) v(col)
           ) v
     ) gt
where cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: I'm really amazed by your mastery of all sql languages.

Comment: Did you really spent time and learnt all SQL languages or you got feeded in your brain like *Neo in Matrix...* :)

Comment: @FelixPamittan . . . They are not *that* different.  Ironically, the above query should work in Postgres, for instance.

Comment: This worked perfect;y.  Is there an equivalent for SQLITE3?

Comment: @KevinMcFadden . . . Alas, no.  SQLite doesn't allow ordering in `group_concat()`, which throws off this logic.  An entirely different method would be needed.